# Why does my forloop and querySelectorAll dont work with multiple div's of the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm trying to make multiple draggable div's with a script. It works fine for 1 div like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/werwer/3zvqm2sa/1/

where I have aquerySelector that gets one class name.

I wish to make multiple draggable divs, sort of like a windows computer. So used a querySelectorAll, put my eventListeners into a forloop to loop through the array, and selected the array item one by one like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/werwer/0n5eLmfv/11/

It completely removed the ability to move all the divs (including the one that originally can move). So I placed a console.log to check if my mouse up and down works for both divs. Here's the fun part: the mouseup and down check worked for the original black div (the one that supposedly can move), but could only detect mouse up for the new white div. So I'm not exactly sure what is going on.

```js
        var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

        for (i = 0; i < wrapper.length - 1; i++) {
        /* multiple event listeners for mouse up and down */
            wrapper[i].addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
                wrapper[i].classList.add("active");
                wrapper[i].addEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
                console.log("check mouse down"); /* checking mouse down */
            });
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                wrapper[i].classList.remove("active");
                wrapper[i].removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
                console.log("check mouse up"); /* checking mouse down */
            });
        }

                /* what moves the divs */
        function onDrag({ movementX, movementY }) {
            let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(wrapper);
            let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
            let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
            wrapper.style.left = `${leftVal + movementX}px`;
            wrapper.style.top = `${topVal + movementY}px`;
        }
```

```css
.projects {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125vh;
    background-image: url(images/laptop.png);
    background-position: 100%;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gamedev-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    left: 16rem;
    width: 40rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #403d39;
}

.gamedev-titlebar {
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EB5E28;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
}

.btn-1 {
    background: turquoise;
}

.btn-2 {
    background: yellow;
}

.btn-3 {
    background: red;
}

.game-btn {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.gamedev-heading {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 369.43px;
height: 40.32px;
left: 408.26px;
top: 2592.77px; */

    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 1rem;

    color: #CCC5B9;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.gamedev-gif {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 16rem;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #fffcf2;

    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.webdev-titlebar {
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 30rem;
    width: 3rem;
    background: #EB5E28;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    pointer-events: none;
}

.web-btn {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    /* margin-right: 1rem; */
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-heading {
    background: none;
    /* position: absolute;
    right: 5rem; */
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 1rem;

    color: #252422;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-content {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;

    position: absolute;
    right: 4rem;
    top: 5rem;

    pointer-events: none;
```

```html
 <div class="projects">
        <div class="gamedev-panel panel">
            <div class="gamedev-titlebar">
                <div class="btn-1 game-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-2 game-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-3 game-btn"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="gamedev-heading">I DEVELOP GAMES</h2>
            <img src="images/game.gif" alt="" class="gamedev-gif">
        </div>
        <div class="webdev-panel panel">
            <div class="webdev-content">
                <h2 class="webdev-heading">I MAKE WEBSITES</h2>
                <img src="images/web.png" alt="" class="webdev-img">
            </div>
            <div class="webdev-titlebar">
                <div class="btn-1 web-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-2 web-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-3 web-btn"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="others-panel"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code needs some changes.

1. don't use variable `i`  in a function inside a loop. variables are all refrence.
2. don't use arrow function to access `this` pointer of current element
3. change your `wrapper[i]` in `onDrag` to `this` like above
4. add `user-select:none` inside the `.panel` to be not selectable in css
5. add mouse out event to current element for the time the mouse jumped out of the screen and the `mouseup` doesn't fire

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

for (i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
    wrapper[i].addEventListener("mousedown",function ()  {
      this.classList.add("active");
      this.addEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
    });
    wrapper[i].addEventListener("mouseup",function ()  {
      this.classList.remove("active");
      this.removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
    });

    wrapper[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function ()  {
      this.removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
    });
}

function onDrag({
  movementX,
  movementY
}) {
  let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this);
  let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
  let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
  this.style.left = `${leftVal + movementX}px`;
  this.style.top = `${topVal + movementY}px`;
}
```

```css
.panel {
  user-select: none;
}
.projects {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125vh;
  background-image: url(images/laptop.png);
  background-position: 100%;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-size: 95%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gamedev-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 16rem;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: #403d39;
}

.gamedev-titlebar {
  height: 3rem;
  background: #EB5E28;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
}

.btn-1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.btn-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.btn-3 {
  background: red;
}

.game-btn {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.gamedev-heading {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 369.43px;
height: 40.32px;
left: 408.26px;
top: 2592.77px; */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: #CCC5B9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gamedev-gif {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 16rem;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: #fffcf2;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webdev-titlebar {
  /* position: absolute; */
  height: 30rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: #EB5E28;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.web-btn {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /* margin-right: 1rem; */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-heading {
  background: none;
  /* position: absolute;
right: 5rem; */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: #252422;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-content {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4rem;
  top: 5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="gamedev-panel panel">
    <div class="gamedev-titlebar">
      <div class="btn-1 game-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-2 game-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-3 game-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="gamedev-heading">I DEVELOP GAMES</h2>
    <img src="images/game.gif" alt="" class="gamedev-gif">
  </div>
  <div class="webdev-panel panel">
    <div class="webdev-content">
      <h2 class="webdev-heading">I MAKE WEBSITES</h2>
      <img src="images/web.png" alt="" class="webdev-img">
    </div>
    <div class="webdev-titlebar">
      <div class="btn-1 web-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-2 web-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-3 web-btn"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="others-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but, whats the difference though? what did i do wrong that you did correctly? Sorry I dont get your pointers at the front so do explain to me

Comment: @WerWer no need to swear. Keep it civil please

Comment: I would STILL delegate - my code does not need to remove event listeners once they are set

Comment: @WerWer yes. they are the same but with little diffrences.  it was all about the refrence of variables. you use `wrapper[i]` in for loop that there is no problem, but using that inside a function at each iteration, causes refrence pointing to wrong variable (i mean the `i` variable) . 
in `ondrag` function there was a diffrent wrror. you called `window.getComputedStyle` on array. so just i changed it to `this` to point the current element that event was fired on.

Comment: @PoryaGrand whats the difference between `this` and `wrapper`? What if I changed it to `wrapper[i]`?

Comment: @WerWer the wrapper is array of htmlElements, the function you called accepts single html element, so it is not possible to pass the wrapper. And for the second one, ‘wrapper[i]’ , it is not possible to use in ‘ondrag’ because there is no ‘i’ in here. The best and safe reference is ‘this’ , although not in arrow function .

Answer (score 0):

Please delegate

Here is an untested version since I am not on a proper device, but it gives the structure

In the onDrag we just test the active element if there is none, we could leave, but as I said, I cannot actually test this to conclusion

I use the same eventlistener for mouseup and down and then instead of add or remove I toggle active depending on the event. If mousedown, add active if up remove active (that is what toggle does)

I add the event listeners to the OUTER div, that wraps ALL the panels, and in the event handler, the e.target is (possibly inside) the panel. So to get the panel itself, I use.closest to make sure we are acting on the wrapper

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".projects");
/* what moves the divs */
const onDrag = ({ movementX, movementY }) => {
  const wrapperPanel = wrapper.querySelector(".panel.active")
  let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(wrapperPanel);
  let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
  let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
  wrapperPanel.style.left = `${leftVal + movementX}px`;
  wrapperPanel.style.top = `${topVal + movementY}px`;
}

const mouse = (e) => {
 const tgt = e.target.closest(".panel");
 if (tgt) tgt.classList.toggle("active",e.type=="mousedown");
};
wrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse)
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseup", mouse)
wrapper.addEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
```

```css
  .projects {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125vh;
  background-image: url(images/laptop.png);
  background-position: 100%;
  background-position-y: center;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-size: 95%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gamedev-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 16rem;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: #403d39;
}

.gamedev-titlebar {
  height: 3rem;
  background: #EB5E28;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
}

.btn-1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.btn-2 {
  background: yellow;
}

.btn-3 {
  background: red;
}

.game-btn {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.gamedev-heading {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 369.43px;
height: 40.32px;
left: 408.26px;
top: 2592.77px; */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: #CCC5B9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gamedev-gif {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 16rem;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 30rem;
  background-color: #fffcf2;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webdev-titlebar {
  /* position: absolute; */
  height: 30rem;
  width: 3rem;
  background: #EB5E28;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.web-btn {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /* margin-right: 1rem; */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-heading {
  background: none;
  /* position: absolute;
    right: 5rem; */
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: #252422;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-content {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4rem;
  top: 5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
```

```html
<div class="projects">
  <div class="gamedev-panel panel">
    <div class="gamedev-titlebar">
      <div class="btn-1 game-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-2 game-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-3 game-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="gamedev-heading">I DEVELOP GAMES</h2>
    <img src="images/game.gif" alt="" class="gamedev-gif">
  </div>
  <div class="webdev-panel panel">
    <div class="webdev-content">
      <h2 class="webdev-heading">I MAKE WEBSITES</h2>
      <img src="images/web.png" alt="" class="webdev-img">
    </div>
    <div class="webdev-titlebar">
      <div class="btn-1 web-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-2 web-btn"></div>
      <div class="btn-3 web-btn"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="others-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! wtf but why did it work like that and didn't work for my original code? The logic looks the same ngl. Although, the console threw up abunch of errors, Im not sure whats going on there

Comment: My code is MUCH simpler than yours. I add the same evenlistener to mouseup and down and then instead of add or remove I toggle active depending on the event. If mousedown, add active if up remove active (that is what toggle does) 
I add the event listeners to the OUTER div, that wraps ALL the panels, and in the event handler, the e.target is (possibly inside) the panel. So to get the panel itself, I use.closest to make sure we are acting on the wrapper

Comment: @mplungjan all works fine and smooth. but does't release the panel if `mouseup` fires outside the windows

Comment: @PoryaGrand thanks - since I am not on a proper device to test, I can’t look and fix that today

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound of `wrapper.length - 1` excludes the last `.panel`.

Additionally, there are various issues with variable bindings:

- `wrapper` in `onDrag` is a `NodeList`, not an HTMLElement. `onDrag` must operate on a specific element of `wrapper`, rather than the whole collection.
- since `i` isn't block-local and is updated in the loop, it will be the last value `i` takes (one past the loop end condition); `wrapper[i]` in the mouse event handlers will only ever refer to one thing. Declaring `i` with `let` will make it block-local, and `wrapper[i]` within the event handlers will then refer to the correct element.

Note that both the above binding issues are already covered by other questions on SO.

Answer (score -1):

You're adding several `mouseup` event listeners to your `document`,you're iterating up to 2 indexes below the final length of your element array, and you're never declaring your `i` variable.

In your event mousemove listener, you're using the `wrapper` variable that you haven't redeclared from your previous code. You can use the `target` property from the `event` object to get the element calling your listener.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

        for (let i = 0; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
        /* multiple event listeners for mouse up and down */
            wrapper[i].addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
                wrapper[i].classList.add("active");
                wrapper[i].addEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
                console.log("check mouse down"); /* checking mouse down */
            });
            
            function mouseMove() {
                wrapper[i].classList.remove("active");
                wrapper[i].removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
                wrapper[i].removeEventListener("mousemove", onDrag);
                console.log("check mouse up"); /* checking mouse down */
            };

            wrapper[i].addEventListener("mouseup", mouseMove);
        }

                /* what moves the divs */
        function onDrag(event) {
            let getStyle = window.getComputedStyle(event.target);
            let leftVal = parseInt(getStyle.left);
            let topVal = parseInt(getStyle.top);
            event.target.style.left = `${leftVal + event.movementX}px`;
            event.target.style.top = `${topVal + event.movementY}px`;
        }
```

```css
.projects {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125vh;
    background-image: url(images/laptop.png);
    background-position: 100%;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-size: 95%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gamedev-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3rem;
    left: 16rem;
    width: 40rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #403d39;
}

.gamedev-titlebar {
    height: 3rem;
    background: #EB5E28;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: right;
}

.btn-1 {
    background: turquoise;
}

.btn-2 {
    background: yellow;
}

.btn-3 {
    background: red;
}

.game-btn {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.gamedev-heading {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* width: 369.43px;
height: 40.32px;
left: 408.26px;
top: 2592.77px; */

    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 1rem;

    color: #CCC5B9;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.gamedev-gif {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    right: 16rem;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 30rem;
    background-color: #fffcf2;

    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

    overflow: hidden;

}

.webdev-titlebar {
    /* position: absolute; */
    height: 30rem;
    width: 3rem;
    background: #EB5E28;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;

    pointer-events: none;
}

.web-btn {
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    /* margin-right: 1rem; */
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-heading {
    background: none;
    /* position: absolute;
    right: 5rem; */
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin-left: 1rem;

    color: #252422;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-content {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.webdev-img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;

    position: absolute;
    right: 4rem;
    top: 5rem;

    pointer-events: none;
```

```html
<div class="projects">
        <div class="gamedev-panel panel">
            <div class="gamedev-titlebar">
                <div class="btn-1 game-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-2 game-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-3 game-btn"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="gamedev-heading">I DEVELOP GAMES</h2>
            <img src="images/game.gif" alt="" class="gamedev-gif">
        </div>
        <div class="webdev-panel panel">
            <div class="webdev-content">
                <h2 class="webdev-heading">I MAKE WEBSITES</h2>
                <img src="images/web.png" alt="" class="webdev-img">
            </div>
            <div class="webdev-titlebar">
                <div class="btn-1 web-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-2 web-btn"></div>
                <div class="btn-3 web-btn"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="others-panel"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please never nest event handlers like that.

Comment: oh shit thanks so much. Now that's fixed, any idea why the function cant run when the event listener is in a forloop?

Comment: @mplungjan whats nesting and is there any reason his code is wrong? It worked completely well for me.

Comment: I would do my very best to never add an event listener inside another event listener. You can easily test what is the current panel just by testing the active in the onDrag